# How to change $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'] in ext_localconf.php - TYPO3 V9?

Tags: typo3

I'm changing $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'] in the AdditonalConfiguration.php at the moment, but I want to move this to my provider extension. The right place for this should be "ext_localconf.php".
But simply moving the code from one file to the other doesn't work.
As a simple example `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['sitename'] = 'special site name';` has no effect in the extension configuration.

I have searched the reference and looked at the "ext_localconf.php" files in other extensions, but didn't find a solution yet.

Comment: Normally, this should work. Documentations ays "All ext_localconf.php files of loaded extensions are included right after the files typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php and typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php during TYPO3 bootstrap." (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FilesAndLocations/Index.html#ext-localconf-php). Are you sure, it's not an caching issue?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I can swear I always cleared the cache when testing. Thanks!

Comment: So you are saying it works now after clearing cache? Can you add an answer yourself? (Currently your question is listed as "without answer" when searching for open questions for TYPO3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, this should work. Documentation "[TYPO3 Explained -> Files and locations](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FilesAndLocations/Index.html#ext-localconf-php)" says

> All ext_localconf.php files of loaded extensions are included right after the files typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php and typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php during TYPO3 bootstrap.

If it's not working, make sure you have *really* cleared the cache.

Two possibilities to clear the cache:

- Backend: Admin tools -> Maintenance -> Flush TYPO3 and PHP Cache
- Console: typo3cms cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

My simple example (sitename) works after clearing the cache.

What confused me was a strange behaviour of the extension configuration for the "mask" extension in version 4.2.3.. If I move the configuration to the provider extension, the content of "mask.json" is ignored. It is really strange and hard to describe. I will try to open another question for this.